# Can't use 'Selection.TypeText' method when writing to Word document from Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm trying to write to a Word document from Excel VBA, and when I try using `.TypeText` method on `Selection` object, I get an error: "Object doesn't support this property or method."

I've read somewhere that Excel VBA doesn't know that I'm referring to the Selection object in my Word document, so I tried the suggested solution, which was to try to do it in a `With` - `End With` block.

Basically I tried this:

```vba
Set WrdApp = New Word.Application
Set DestDoc = WrdApp.Documents.Add
With DestDoc
   .Activate
   .Select
   .Selection.TypeText Text:="Test"
End With
```

But it always reports the same error on the `.Selection.TypeText` line.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub WriteToWord()

Dim WrdApp As New Word.Application
Dim WrdDoc As Document
Dim WrdSel As Selection

WrdApp.Visible = True
Set WrdDoc = WrdApp.Documents.Add
Set WrdSel = WrdApp.Selection

WrdSel.TypeText "Test"

End Sub
```

You were pretty close with your code. The error you were having is that there is no `.Selection` property for `DestDoc`. You could have done it outside instead. However, your style is not best practice, so refer to my style above so you can identify exactly which is what. :)

Let is know if this helps.

Comment: One more thing @BK201... You made me realize what my key mistake was. What I'd do intuitively is `Set WrdSel=WrdDoc.Selection` expecting that `WrdDoc` is a document object generated by `Set WrdDoc=WrdApp.Documents.Add`, and that I should be defining `WrdSel` object as an element in `WrdDoc` object. I'm still a bit confused though, as I don't really see why `.Selection` property works on `WrdApp` and not on `WrdDoc` -- I guess I don't really understand the difference between ´WrdApp´and `WrdDoc`, or to be more precise, I don't understand the nature of  `WrdApp` object.

Comment: One tip: don't think that Word VBA acts like Excel VBA. In Excel, it's easy to create an `Application --> Workbook --> Worksheet` flow and work on the worksheet when you want to type in stuff. In Word, it doesn't really work that way. The `Document` property holds methods that are for the document's "formatting" like `Background`, `Page Setup`, etc, but it's the Application level you want for text manipulation. Actually, in the code above, `Set WrdDoc = ` can be removed without repercussions at all. Weird, right? :)

Comment: Thanks @BK201, it's all much clearer now! It's quite weird how Word VBA works indeed. Thanks again, you've been very helpful! :)